# launch database mirroring monitor grayed out in SQL server 2014

Tags: sql-server, ssms, mirroring

I have 2 servers configured with mirroring each other. Both the servers are principal & Mirror servers each other. From the 2nd Server launch database mirroring monitor is working fine but from 1st server launch database mirroring monitor is showing grayed out. Both server services are running with the same administrator account. The below screenshot is for 1st server. Can you please help me how to enable this launch database mirroring option in SQL server 2014 ?
[image]

Comment: No. Currently we have SQL server 2014 SSMS version is 12.0.6024.0 was there. I have not updated to latest version.

Comment: Might try to get 18.3 and see if your problem is resolved. You can both versions side by side.

Comment: But in one server it was working fine from another server we are facing this issue. Both servers have same configurations and same versions of SSMS. So can you please explain me why it was happening for 1 server only ?

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem - turns out if the first DB in the list is in restoring (mirroring) state that server will have this issue.  Solved it by adding an empty DB "aaa" as the first DB in the list.